# Python function variable scoping and expressions

Tags: python, variables, scope, global-variables, local-variables

I notice that global variables in Python (3.9.10) can be accessed within functions, but not mutated as shown below:

No error:

```py
def absolute_value(number):
    print(y)
    if number < 0:
        return -number
    return number

y = 10
result = absolute_value(5)
```

Error:

```py
def absolute_value(number):
    y = y + 2
    print(y)
    if number < 0:
        return -number
    return number

y = 10
result = absolute_value(5)
```

I would like to know the more general mechanism - which is, without using the `global` keyword, what's the most one can do with a global variable within a function's local namespace?

Comment: When you *"assign"* something to a variable, Python marks that variable as a "local variable". This happens at function's creation time. So in runtime, Python checks the local namespace for local variables. In the second example, in line `y = y + 2`, it tries to find `y` in local name space. What is `y` ? Nothing yet. So the right hand side of the assignment fails.

Comment: But if you don't assign to `y`(like in first example), it will find it in global namespace. It follows the LEGB rule.